# pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2067: FAILED: MQRC_SELECTOR_ERROR

Tags: python, ibm-mq, pymqi

I am trying to read some MQ varaibles using python, for example :

```
print('High Queue depth:', qq.inquire(pymqi.CMQC.MQIA_HIGH_Q_DEPTH))
```

when I run it I got this error :

```
 File "depth.py", line 32, in <module>
print('High Queue depth:', qq.inquire(pymqi.CMQC.MQIA_HIGH_Q_DEPTH))
File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pymqi.py", line 1766, in inquire
raise MQMIError(rv[-2], rv[-1])
pymqi.MQMIError: MQI Error. Comp: 2, Reason 2067: FAILED: MQRC_SELECTOR_ERROR
```

Answer (score 0):

The MQ reason code [MQRC_SELECTOR_ERROR (2067)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.tro.doc/q041350_.htm) means that you cannot inquire that attribute (MQIA_HIGH_Q_DEPTH) on that object.

MQIA_HIGH_Q_DEPTH is not a queue attribute, it is a constant value used inside an event message. I suspect you are trying to inquire the current depth of your queue? If so, the attribute you should be using is MQIA_CURRENT_Q_DEPTH. You can see the full list of MQINQ-able attributes of queue in [Table 1. MQINQ attribute selectors for queues](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.ref.dev.doc/q101840_.htm), so if that's not the one you wanted (my guess) then you can select one that is appropriate from that list.