Cached JMS Session object is printing as null in JmsTemplate
Our application is a JAVA back end app running inside a Tomcat. In a high level it reads input from IBM MQ, process it, persists it in the ORACLE DB and writes the output to an MQ. It is a distributed two phase commit transaction world where Atomikos serves as a transaction manager. We use Spring JMS API. Currently the set up is we are in JAVA 11 and now we are trying to upgrade the app to JAVA 17.
We use org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory with com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean as connection factory bean. For every polling of the MQ messages in JAVA 11, the below logs gets printed out from org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.class in the spring-jms jar.
"Executing callback on JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueSession@39f839d6"
Dependencies used:
com.ibm.mq.allclient - 7.5.0.0,
spring-jms - 5.3.x,
Atomikos - 5.0.8 (free version)
Now when we upgraded to JAVA 17, the dependencies are also upgraded to the latest compatible.
Dependeicies used:
com.ibm.mq.jakarta.client - 9.4.0.0,
spring-jms - 6.1.5,
Atomikos - 6.0.0 (free version)
But now, after this upgrade, we get the logs as,
"Executing callback on JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: null"
Enabling the log trace, we get,
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Returned cached Session: null
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Found cached JMS Session for mode 0: null
Executing callback on JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: null
org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory - Found cached JMS MessageConsumer for destination [queue:///XXXXX]: atomikosJmsMessageConsumerWrapper for com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQQueueReceiver@430eac26
We are not allowed to connect directly to the test queue managers from local machine hence with a limited debugging opportunity, we found that in the JAVA 11 version of the code, when we upgrade the com.ibm.mq.allclient jar iteratively, we found that things are fine until 9.2.3.0 and this cached session prints out to null starting from 9.2.4.0
From the change logs of 9.2.4.0, I'm not able to find anything specific that could bring out this behavior except there is a JAVA 17 upgrade here.
Can anyone give us a clear picture please?
UPDATE: 25/Jun/24
Let me add this extra info. I'm migrating the Tomcat too from 9 to 10.1.x which has servlet 6 and thus I have to migrate everything from jakarta to javax.
Today I have enabled the trace of IBM mq client jars and below is the finding. I ran both the versions of app (current version and the to be upgraded version)
For keeping it simple, Im just providing the log that is of importance.
Both the logs are almost the same with the same exception happening in both the versions except the package name differences and the all important highlighted part.
IBM MQ trace logs of the upgraded version of app:
Important part in the logs
c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection                                  -  }  createXAQueueSession() returns [null]
c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection                                    }  createXASession() returns [null]
    c.i.m.c.w.v.base.internal.MQQueueManager                               ----+---  }  errorOccurred(MQException)
    c.i.m.c.w.v.base.internal.MQQueueManager(MQManagedObject)              ----+---  !  getString(int,int)<throwIndex 2>, MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2067'. [com.ibm.mq.MQException]
    c.i.m.c.w.v.jms.internal.MQXASession(MQSession)                        ----+-  X  <init>(MQConnection,MQQueueManager,boolean,int)<catchIndex 2>
    MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2067'. [com.ibm.mq.MQException] at:
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQManagedObject.getString(MQManagedObject.java:337)
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQManagedObject.getAttributeString(MQManagedObject.java:248)
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQSession.<init>(MQSession.java:494)
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession.<init>(MQXASession.java:128)
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXAConnection.createXASession(MQXAConnection.java:139)
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsXAConnectionImpl.createXASession(JmsXAConnectionImpl.java:125)
    com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl.createXAQueueSession(JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl.java:136)
    com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection.createXAQueueSession(MQXAQueueConnection.java:87)
    com.ibm.mq.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection.createXASession(MQXAQueueConnection.java:105)
    com.atomikos.jms.internal.AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy.createSession(AtomikosJmsConnectionProxy.java:132)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    com.atomikos.util.DynamicProxySupport.callProxiedMethod(DynamicProxySupport.java:164)
    com.atomikos.util.DynamicProxySupport.invoke(DynamicProxySupport.java:121)
    jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy365.createSession(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory.createSession(SingleConnectionFactory.java:525)
    org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.getSession(CachingConnectionFactory.java:263)
    org.springframework.jms.connection.SingleConnectionFactory$SharedConnectionInvocationHandler.invoke(SingleConnectionFactory.java:705)
    jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy366.createSession(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.jms.support.JmsAccessor.createSession(JmsAccessor.java:228)
    org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.access$100(JmsTemplate.java:93)
    org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate$JmsTemplateResourceFactory.createSession(JmsTemplate.java:1214)
    org.springframework.jms.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalSession(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:327)
    org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:514)
    org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receiveSelected(JmsTemplate.java:773)
    org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.receive(JmsTemplate.java:749)
    com.util.io.jms.JmsTemplateImpl.access$201(JmsTemplateImpl.java:38)
    com.util.io.jms.JmsTemplateImpl$5.doAction(JmsTemplateImpl.java:239)
    com.util.io.jms.JmsTemplateImpl.executeJmsActionHandler(JmsTemplateImpl.java:348)
    com.util.io.jms.JmsTemplateImpl.receive(JmsTemplateImpl.java:229)
    com.util.io.jms.JMSInputSource.read(JMSInputSource.java:111)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy361.read(Unknown Source)
    com.workflow.SimpleMessageSource.supplyMessage(SimpleMessageSource.java:74)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:392)
    org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:223)
    jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy362.supplyMessage(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216)
    jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy343.getNextMessage(Unknown Source)
    jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor149.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:354)
    org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:216)
    jdk.proxy4/jdk.proxy4.$Proxy343.getNextMessage(Unknown Source)
    jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor149.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:281)
    org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:265)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.MethodInvokingMessageSource.doReceive(MethodInvokingMessageSource.java:113)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractMessageSource.receive(AbstractMessageSource.java:142)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.receiveMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:212)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:443)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:412)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
    org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
    org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
    org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
    org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:96)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
    Object ClassLoader = ParallelWebappClassLoader^M
      context: <projName>^M
      delegate: false^M
    ----------> Parent Classloader:^M
    java.net.URLClassLoader@710726a3^M
    
    [25/06/24 05:15:08.862.0Y]  00000002 CurrentThread ClassLoader = ParallelWebappClassLoader^M
      context: <projName>^M
      delegate: false^M
    ----------> Parent Classloader:^M
    java.net.URLClassLoader@710726a3^M
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ----+-  d   Setting QSGName to null <null>
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ----+-  d   QSGName set to null <null>
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession(MQSession)                      ----+  }  <init>(MQConnection,MQQueueManager,boolean,int)
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ----+  {  <init>(MQConnection,MQQueueManager,MQSession,JmqiXAResource) [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXAConnection@6320ee8a] [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQQueueManager@2906bf91] [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQSession@6320ee8a] [c.i.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@75b8f7c0]
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession(MQSession)                      ----+-  d  setQM(MQQueueManager) setter [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.base.internal.MQQueueManager@2906bf91]
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ----+-  d   com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession [Set MQXASession resolved variables to those within the session]
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ----+  }  <init>(MQConnection,MQQueueManager,MQSession,JmqiXAResource)
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession(WMQPropertyContext)             ----+  d  setPropertyContext(JmsPropertyContext) setter <as-before>
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsPropertyContextImpl)   ----+  d  setProviderPropertyContext(JmsPropertyContext) setter [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession@23d0b7d0]
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession(MQSession)                      ----+  d  setDistTransactionMode(int) setter [1(0x1)]
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXAConnection                              ----  }  createXASession(JmsPropertyContext) returns [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession@23d0b7d0]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           ----  d  setProviderSession(ProviderSession) setter [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession@23d0b7d0]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl(JmsXAConnectionImpl)   ---  }  createXASession() returns <as-before>
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl                        --  }  createXAQueueSession() returns <as-before>
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueSession(MQSession)                          --  d  setDelegate(JmsSession) setter <as-before>
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection                                  -  }  createXAQueueSession() returns [null]
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection                                    }  createXASession() returns [null]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsXASessionImpl)           {  getXAResource()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           -  {  checkNotClosed()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           -  }  checkNotClosed()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           -  d  getProviderSession() getter [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession@23d0b7d0]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsXASessionImpl)         -  d  getProviderXASession() getter [c.i.m.c.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQXASession@23d0b7d0]
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 -  d  getXAResource() getter [c.i.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@75b8f7c0]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsXASessionImpl)           }  getXAResource() returns [c.i.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@75b8f7c0]
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueSession(MQXASession)                          d  getXAResource() getter [c.i.mq.jmqi.JmqiXAResource@75b8f7c0]
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection(MQConnection)                      {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl(JmsConnectionImpl)     -  {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  {  enableMessageReferenceProcessing()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ---  d  com.ibm.msg.client.jakarta.wmq.compat.jms.internal.MQSession enableMessageReferenceProcessing() [Message reference processing is always enabled when using MQ messaging provider migration mode, so there is nothing to do here]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  }  enableMessageReferenceProcessing()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXAConnection(MQConnection)                --  {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXAConnection(MQConnection)                ---  {  notifyBrowsers()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXAConnection                              ----  d   notifying 0 browsers of state STARTED <null>
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXAConnection(MQConnection)                ---  }  notifyBrowsers()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXAConnection(MQConnection)                --  }  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl(JmsConnectionImpl)     --  {  fixClientID()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl(JmsConnectionImpl)     --  }  fixClientID()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl$ReentrantDoubleLock              ---  {  getExclusiveLock()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl$ReentrantDoubleLock              ---  }  getExclusiveLock()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ---  {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession(MQSession)                      ----  {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession(MQSession)                      ----  }  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQSession                                   ----  {  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQSession                                   ----  }  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.w.c.jms.internal.MQXASession                                 ---  }  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.State                                           ---  d  setState(int) setter [1(0x1)]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           ---  f  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl$ReentrantDoubleLock              ---  {  unlockExclusiveLock()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsSessionImpl$ReentrantDoubleLock              ---  }  unlockExclusiveLock()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  }  start()
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.State                                           --  d  setState(int) setter [1(0x1)]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueConnectionImpl(JmsConnectionImpl)     -  }  start()
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueConnection(MQConnection)                      }  start()
    c.i.m.jakarta.jms.MQXAQueueSession(MQSession)                            {  createQueue(String) [XXXXX]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           -  {  createQueue(String) [XXXXX]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  {  checkSynchronousUsage(String) [createQueue]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           ---  d  isAsync() getter [false]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  }  checkSynchronousUsage(String)
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  {  checkQueueDomain(String) [createQueue]
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  }  checkQueueDomain(String)
    c.i.m.c.j.jms.internal.JmsXAQueueSessionImpl(JmsSessionImpl)           --  d  isAsync() getter [false]

But the highlighted logs for the current version of app turns out to be as below.
c.i.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection                                         -  }  createXAQueueSession() returns [c.i.mq.jms.MQXAQueueSession@69526d8f]
c.i.mq.jms.MQXAQueueConnection                                           }  createXASession() returns [c.i.mq.jms.MQXAQueueSession@69526d8f]
And this object seems to be the exact one that gets printed out in the app logs.
Executing callback on JMS Session: Cached JMS Session: com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAQueueSession@69526d8f
As said this discrepancy didnt cause any issue in reading or writing the messages but we would never know what it could bring up in production.

If you didn't upgrade MQ on the server side or use a version that isn't compatible with Jakarta this won't work. You have fallen in trhe trap of doing too much at the same time. There is no need to upgrade Spring to a newer version if you want to use Java17. First upgrade java, check if things work.

I missed to provide an another important info. We are upgrading to Tomcat 10.1.x from version 9. This means the Tomcat uses Servlet 6.0 which uses jakarta classes instead of javax. This means I have to move to springframework 6.x for it to be jakarta and Java 17 compatible. Same with IBM mq jars and atomikos. @M.Deinum

You cannot upgrade to a newer IBM MQ jar if you are not upgrading MQ itself as well. As stated before you are doing too much in 1 go.

Nonsense. You can have completely independent versions of MQ and the client jars

Yeah it all looks a big jump because Java 17 and Tomcat by itself is a major change of things. Especially with this javax to jakarta almost catching up to a level that you cannot ignore it anymore, it has knock on effect everywhere. Tomcat10+Java17+Spring6+IBMmqJakarta-9.x.x.x+Atomikos-V6. All of them are tied together and will force you to go all together. @M.Deinum

No it doesn't... You don't need Spring 6 to run on Java17. Spring 5.3 will run perfectly fine on Java17. Doe that first before moving on. Take smaller steps. And as stated you will also have to upgrade MQ on the server not only the client. If you don't upgrade your MQ server it will not work, it isn't just an upgrade of the client!.

As noted, you are moving from Tomcat 9 (Java EE) to Tomcat 10 (Jakarta EE).  This is a lot of change. The ""Executing callback on JMS Session" is the transaction commit.   The transaction manager is doing the callback to commit the transaction, but the connection is NULL.  Maybe setting the the IBM client logging to TRACE would be informative.

Could you please clarify if the log message you are hoping to remove is informational, warning or error? IE. Is your polling application affected? If your polling is affected, please explain how, and please share the code that is affected.

@DougGrove yes this is a lot of change and unfortunately we dont have the luxury to update one by one as of now. I have provided the trace logs of IBM and the likely place of this issue. Can you please check?

@chughts this is more of an info I believe but the content of it raised the alarm. Provided more info in the description.

Please clarify the scope of your XA Transaction is it QM1->Oracle->QM2 or something else?

In the stack trace, com.util.io.jms.JmsTemplateImpl.receive() is being set up to listen for a message.  A Connection already exists (MQXAConnection@6320ee8a) , and a Session is being created (MQXASession@23d0b7d0).  I have no idea why the Session init is failing.  It does seem to me that the issue lies in MQ.

@RaviShankar Have you managed to check the queue manager log? Is it possible that the app permissions are correct in relation to the selector and 2067? This post might be a useful reference > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34073954/pymqi-mqmierror-mqi-error-comp-2-reason-2067-failed-mqrc-selector-error <

@M.Deinum this statement is wrong: "And as stated you will also have to upgrade MQ on the server not only the client. If you don't upgrade your MQ server it will not work, it isn't just an upgrade of the client!." There is rarely a need to upgrade the client and server at the same time. Read IBM MQ 7.x, 8.0, 9.0, 9.1, 9.2, 9.3 and 9.4 compatibility with previous versions for details.

There is if you are upgrading to JakartaEE afaik, those need to be compatible. It is not about previous versions but newer versions. At least it didn't work when we encountered the same.

Things works as expected when we change the SHARECNV property of the SVRCONN channel from 0 to default 10. Not sure about the reason and background though.

I wonderif this new 9.4 setting would have anything to do with the problem: Sharing a TCP/IP connection in IBM MQ classes for JMS.  Have you tried setting SHARECNV to 1, this would work similar to 0 but has the added benefits of the newer 7.0+ channel features.
